# How to avoid rate limit when building an app on top of Google Drive for a large audience?

Tags: google-drive-api

Maybe I'm missing something but is there a way to build a free app that integrate Google Drive without having the rate limits "per app"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not going to release the source code (e.g not making easy for other developers to "steal" your application's client ID and secret), you can request more quota from the APIs Console page under the "Quotas" pane.

For open-source project, I would advise in asking the user/developer to create their own API Project from the APIs Console and provide a "wizard" type setup for them to enter the necessary information.

Comment: Ok understood, thanks for your answer Alain. And what if the app is a one time purchase like for example $0.99? Can we still safely build on top of Drive? Will you allow more quota or will we have to pay for it?

Comment: Any news for this clarification @Alain? Thx a lot!

Comment: You can safely ask for more quota. We currently don't have plan to charge for additional quota but will review all requests.